# Do constant maximum lift to drag ratio variable pitch propeller exist?

Tags: propeller, constant-speed-propeller, variable-pitch

Are there variable pitch propellers, where pitch is set so that the blades constantly are at their maximum lift to drag ratio AoA, whatever the incoming relative wind speed & direction?

Such a variable pitch propeller would be powered by some electric engine, able to equally produce torque for clockwise and anti-clockwise operation.

Such a variable pitch propeller would be free on its pitch axis, able to rotate 360°, each blade being mounted on two ball bearings, inside propeller's hub. This way maximum aerodynamic efficiency could be reached whatever the needs:

take off at low relative pitch,
cruise at some higher pitch,
ability to produce efficient reverse thrust after landing.
Each of these at maximum lift to drag ratio AoA.

Each blade is balanced about this pitch axis, so that it is statically stable, and aerodynamically **always trying to pitch up by its own aerodynamic configuration**, towards its best lift/drag ratio angle of attack.

*Each blade becomes an individual glider/flying wing, trying to pitch up.*

For the sake of understanding, imagine a propeller with trailing edge tabs set at an angle allowing only thrust generation, regardless of the direction of rotation of the propeller.

[image: te tab]

This tab is not a viable way to build such a blade, it may instead look like some conventional blade, having some negative incidence blade tip combined with swept back tip, or some standard geometry, with a reflex airfoil, or both, or something else.

[image]

[image]

The idea here could be to have an automated variable pitch prop with the least amount of moving parts, where pitch is set by aerodynamic forces at its optimal angle. Instead of going for constant rpm, this one goes towards constant maximum lift.

For instance, cutting power off would induce some reverse windmilling, adding power in windmilling direction will generate reverse thrust.

During forward flight, pitch would adjust on resultant airplane's velocity + blade's rotational velocity.

Question is : Are there propellers of this kind? If not what are the drawbacks I don't see?

Comment: I imagine it is hard to design a blade such that every portion of the blade fit your condition at each aircraft and/or rotational speed. GIven a rotational speed, the air speed vary by a great amount along the blade, thus I guess the blade twist must also vary with aircraft's speed.

Comment: This idea would seem to have something in common with the "freewing" concept, where the wing is free change angle-of-incidence in flight in order to maintain some given constant angle-of-attack in response to gusts, etc.

Comment: In the propeller context, does the fact that the whole prop blade can never be designed to have a constant angle-of-attack from root to tip, at least over the whole envelope of possible airspeeds and prop rpm, possibly negate some of the possible theoretical advantages of this idea?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, and how would you actually monitor and set the optimal L/D ratio?  I.e. how would you measure and display the information?  Because optimizing prop efficiency is the goal of constant speed props, it just happens that measuring RPM is way easier than mounting a miniature AOA sensor on each blade…  (Unless you have a better idea!)

Comment: @MichaelHall I'm not trying to solve anything that already works, this was about knowing if something had been attempted along these lines. RPM doesn't either tell anything about optimal AOA, it just tells about RPM being constant relative to maximum available power output

Comment: What would stop it from simply aligning with the relative wind?  If you expect an airfoil to perform work it needs to be loaded.  Common sense tells me that if aerodynamic forces are allowed to dictate pitch it would always seek the path of least resistance.  How do you envision it being able to hold a positive angle of attack under load?

Comment: @MichaelHall it is like a trim tab on a rudder. If the trim tab is set at an angle, the rudder will be loaded as long as this tab angle is unchanged. The fact that the system tab+rudder can in itself weathervane does not mean the rudder is not loaded.

Comment: @quietflyer other kind of variable pitch propellers cannot do that either. fwiu, to do so the blades should twist or untwist themselves according to pitch and airplane speed variations

Comment: OK, I follow you.  Good question, but my gut tells me that they would twist themselves towards neutral under a hard load so you'd loose a lot of power.  Hopefully someone smarter than me can explain clearly why my instinct is correct...

Comment: @qq jkztd beautiful presentation.  Conceptually, its seems dependent on forward speed and throttle, whereas we use *controllable* throttle and pitch to *create* forward airspeed.  A graph of optimal AoA (for RPM and airspeed axes) would only be a single line.  All other combinations would produce different AoA.

Comment: I'm no engineer, but this just looks like unnecessary reinvention of the wheel.  Plus without some mechanism to force the blade to flip once the rotation speed hits zero, it would either not flip around or have an impractical delay in changing direction for landing reverse thrust.

Comment: "*Are there variable pitch propellers, where pitch is set so that the blades constantly are at their maximum lift to drag ratio AoA*" I don't know if I get it right but any variable pitch propeller has its pitch changed (more or less automatically) to work at its AoA of max lift/drag. Or are you asking something different?

Comment: @quietflyer The only props that actually untwist while also conveniently increase their pitch as airspeed incresases, are early aviation wooden props, that where swept back along an arc shape. (looking like an "S" ) Early morphing composites!

Comment: @sophit to me it seems variable pitch props that equip piston or turboprop engines do actually are "constant induced drag propellers" rather than seeking for best AoA

Comment: just found those early props are called ["scimitar propellers"](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopify.com%2Fs%2Ffiles%2F1%2F0578%2F9125%2Fproducts%2Fparagon_american_airplane_propeller_company_scimitar_7ft_wooden_antique_1919_9.JPG%3Fv%3D1571272489&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=d3af271b034d09d7c6384a6982fe3b2b5eaf2495265298ecc924cc8f6c4ea484&ipo=images)

Comment: Variable pitch propellers are made work at their max lift/drag ratio so that their [efficiency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20nHU.png) is optimal for a wide range of working conditions. But again: is this what you were asking?

Comment: @sophit no clue what i'm actually asking for, lack of tools at the moment, but I'll build one and test it when possible, and share results here if relevant

Answer (score 0):

Yes, considering a prop more analogous to a stabilator than a horizontal stabilizer and elevator (and trim tab).

Optimal AoA can be found in cruise by comparing prop pitch to forward airspeed at a given RPM or, most accurately, fuel consumption.  For props, lift is **thrust**.  Maximum cruise pitch efficiency has already been solved.

A major factor in efficiency is *engine friction*.  This is why lower RPM and coarser pitch may actually burn less fuel per mile.

Also, prop pitch may need to be other than optimal AoA, such as feathering.

With take off and go around, you don't care about efficiency, max thrust is needed.  Higher engine RPM and finer pitch can squeeze a bit more power out of the engine/prop.

So, some good thinking here, in search of an application niche unfilled.  A main issue to reconsider is that there are many throttle and forward airspeed variables for climbing, level flight, and descending flight. Prop AoA must be controlled, rather than to freely pitch because any rpm other than optimal rpm will produce a non-optimal AoA.

**BREAKING NEWS**

A pitch control system is being developed for [turbo fans](https://www.asme.org/topics-resources/content/turbine-fuel-efficiency-fitting-a-pitch).  Apparently, someone *does* think this is a good idea ... for fan jets.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one please?

Comment: Robert, I think you missed the central premise of the question.  It's asking if any variable pitch props exist that establish and maintain pitch solely from aerodynamic forces.  i.e. free rotating at the hub, not held in place of moved by springs, oil pressure, or counterweights.  You answered "yes" to that question, but offered no actual example.  Your answer is really just generic discussion about a few topics associated with standard constant speed props.  You haven't actually answered the question that was asked...

Comment: Just as an afterthought, some WW2 trainers had a "2 speed" prop pitch adjust that might be great on recreational aircraft (takeoff and cruise).  As with trucks, more gears enable a smaller, lighter, more fuel efficient engine (although 10 speeds with a stick just might be a bit much).

Answer (score 0):

take look at variable pitch rotors on helicopters. They are controlled by the pilot. they are not automatic. I know of only manually operated one.
"antitorque pedals allow the pilot to control the pitch angle of the tail rotor blades, which in forward flight puts the helicopter in longitudinal trim and, while at a hover, enables the pilot to turn the helicopter 360°."[image]

The term is calculated for any particular airspeed by measuring the lift generated, then dividing by the drag at that speed.
[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the question, and it's somewhat unclear what is being said & what point is being made. Please edit your answer so that it is more clear and a more direct answer to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: The graph is great.  What the OP wants for the prop is to control AoA with a trim tab of some type.